# Provably total functions in $\mathsf{Q}$

Tags: logic, recursion, computability, proof-theory, peano-axioms

I was interested in the relations between induction and recursion, and so a natural question (to my mind, anyway), was how much we can prove without appealing to induction, i.e. which functions are provably recursive in $\mathsf{Q}$ (Robinson Arithmetic). To recap, a function $f$ is provably recursive in an arithmetic theory $T$ iff there is a $\Sigma_1$ formula $\phi$ in the language of $T$ such that (i) $f(n)=m$ iff $T \vdash \phi(n, m)$ and (ii) $T \vdash \forall x \exists !y \phi(x, y)$.

Now, I *thought* that a function was provably recursive in $\mathsf{Q}$ iff it is a recursive function. My reasoning was as follows. A function is recursive iff it is representable in $\mathsf{Q}$, and, it is a well-known result (see [this article for discussion](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.00658.pdf)) that representability in $\mathsf{Q}$ is equivalent to strong representability in $\mathsf{Q}$ which is equivalent to being provably total in $\mathsf{Q}$.

However, I immediately became confused, because, if I understood Fairtlough and Wainer ("Hierarchies of Provably Recursive Functions") correctly, the provable recursive functions of $\mathsf{I}\Sigma^0_1$ are exactly the primitive recursive functions. Since $\mathsf{I}\Sigma^0_1$ extends $\mathsf{Q}$, it is stronger than $\mathsf{Q}$, and therefore cannot prove that *fewer* functions are total. To add to the mess, I remember (but may be misremembering) Nelson claiming that $\mathsf{Q}$ cannot prove that exponentiation is total. If that is so, then obviously $\mathsf{Q}$ cannot prove that all recursive functions are total. But, again, I may be misremembering Nelson's claim.

So, on the one hand, it seems that every recursive functions is provably total in $\mathsf{Q}$, but, on the other, it seems that not even all primitive recursive functions are total in $\mathsf{Q}$. Clearly I have gone wrong somewhere.

> **Question 1:** So, what *are* the provably total functions in $\mathsf{Q}$?

And, depending on the answer to this question, I have one or the other further question:

> **Question 2a:** If $\mathsf{Q}$ does *not* prove, for every recursive function, that it is total, then what have I misunderstood about the equivalence between representability in $\mathsf{Q}$ and being provably total?

> **Question 2b:** If every recursive function *is* provably total in $\mathsf{Q}$, then what have I misunderstood about $\mathsf{I}\Sigma^0_1$? Is there a different definition of provably total in play?

Any help in sorting this out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is a subtle difference between two notions: "provable totality" (in the sense of Salehi) and "provable recursiveness." The former coincides with recursiveness, but the latter does not. Consequently, in my experience - and this explains my parenthetical above - both "provably total" and "provably recursive" are used to refer to the narrower class of functions.

---

Here are the relevant definitions:

- A function $f$ is **(Salehi-)provably total** *(and these are the functions Salehi discusses)* iff there is some formula $\eta$ such that:

  - $T\vdash$ "For each $x$ there is exactly one $y$ such that $\eta(x,y)$."
  - For each $a\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $T\vdash\eta(\underline{a},\underline{f(a)})$.
- A function is **provably recursive** *(and these are the functions you describe in your OP)* iff the above holds for some $\Sigma^0_1$ formula $\eta$.

The argument Salehi gives does indeed show that every total recursive function is provaby total in $\mathsf{Q}$. However, it does **not** show the same for provable recursiveness, and indeed provable recursiveness and (genuine) total recursiveness **never** coincide for reasonable theories since we can always diagonalize against proofs in such theories.

*Note that we can similarly divide up the various representability notions into their "boldface" and "$\Sigma^0_1$" versions; however, this doesn't actually change anything now (and it's a good exercise to verify this).*

Precisely because of the coincision above, provable totality in Salehi's sense isn't very interesting, and so these days (in my experience at least) "provably total" is usually used as a synonym for "provably recursive;" for example, see [Hajek/Pudlak Remark (IV)$3.2$](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pl/1235421933) or [this nice survey of Weiermann](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4617258?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents). In particular, when we say "The provably total functions of $\mathsf{I\Sigma_1}$ are the primitive recursive functions," we're referring to provable recursiveness.

---

So what exactly *are* the provably recursive functions in $\mathsf{Q}$? Well, I can't actually seem to find an answer to this question. But this isn't too surprising I think: since $\mathsf{Q}$ is so weak this is a less interesting question than for stronger arithmetic theories.

That said, here's what I know (for simplicity I'll refer to functions rather than appropriate $\Sigma^0_1$ formulas). Let $\mathfrak{Q}$ be the class of $\mathsf{Q}$-provably recursive functions. The most obvious members of $\mathfrak{Q}$ are the "termlike functions," by which I mean the functions of the form $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
p_1(x) & \mbox{ if }\varphi_1(x)\mbox{ holds }\\
p_2(x) & \mbox{ if }\varphi_2(x)\mbox{ holds}\\
...\\
p_n(x) & \mbox{ if }\varphi_n(x)\mbox{ holds}\\
\end{cases}$$
for some sequence $p_1,..., p_n$ of polynomials and some sequence $\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n$ of $\Delta^0_1$ formulas which $\mathsf{Q}$ proves partition the universe. Trivially each termlike function is $\mathsf{Q}$-provably recursive.

However, this doesn't exhaust $\mathfrak{Q}$: we can to a certain extent get around the weakness of $\mathsf{Q}$ by looking at tame initial segments. Basically, say that a number $x$ is **tame** if "enough arithmetic" holds below $x$ (e.g. for all $y,z<x$ we have that $y^z$ is defined - it's a good exercise to pin down a sufficient notion of tameness here). Tameness is a $\Delta_1$ property, and $\mathsf{Q}$ proves that the set of tame numbers is an initial segment of the universe. So we can define a function $g$ which on the "tame part" diagonalizes against termlike functions and is always $0$ on the "wild part." Since every standard natural number is tame, we will in fact have that $g$ is not termlike.

Of course, this is pretty silly since this $g$ is *eventually equal* to a termlike function. So let's leap ahead:

> For $T$ a theory of arithmetic possibly containing more funtion symbols than just $+$ and $\times$ (e.g. $\mathsf{PRA}$ or $\mathsf{PA}$ + a primitive for exponentiation), say that a $T$-provably recursive function $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ is **$T$-special** iff for every term $t(x_1,..., x_n, y_1,...,y_k)$ we have $$T\vdash\forall a_1,...,a_k\exists b\forall c_1>b, ..., c_n>b[f(c_1,...,c_n)\not=t(c_1,...,c_n, a_1,...,a_k)].$$ Basically, the $T$-special functions are those which are provably eventually different from each term function (with parameters allowed). Write "$\mathfrak{Spec}(T)$" for the set of $T$-special functions.

Before going forward, let me make a couple quick observations:

- We could also look at what happens if we replace "cofinally often" with "coboundedly often," but this doesn't seem as natural: for example, taking $T=\mathsf{PA}$ the function sending $x$ to $2^x$ if $x$ is even and to $0$ otherwise would count as special by this latter definition, while in my opinion it clearly shouldn't.
- We have to be careful in how we interpret $\mathfrak{Spec}(T)$: we can have a conservative extension $S$ of $T$ with $\mathfrak{Spec}(S)\subsetneq\mathfrak{Spec}(T)$ (consider expansions by definitions). So in order to treat $\mathfrak{Spec}(T)$ as a measure of the strength of $T$, we need to restrict attention to a single language - say, $\{+,\times\}$. Once we've done that, however, things are reasonably nice since if $T$ and $S$ are theories in the same language then $T\subseteq S$ implies $\mathfrak{Spec}(T)\subseteq\mathfrak{Spec}(S)$.

In my opinion, within a limited language like $\{+,\times\}$ a paucity of special functions can reasonably be considered a kind of weakness. And so this raises a natural question:

> Does $\mathfrak{Spec}(\mathsf{Q})=\emptyset$?

I would tentatively interpret a positive answer to this question as **a precise sense in which $\mathsf{Q}$-provable recursiveness is pretty trivial**. But I don't know whether this is in fact the case; since it seems interesting, I've asked about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802162/can-all-mathsfq-provably-recursive-functions-be-frequently-termlike).

Comment: So the problem with my reasoning seems to be the step from representability to provable totality. But the article I linked attributes to Verena Huber-Dyson the theorem according to which strong representability implies provable totality (pp. 13-4), and claims that in $\mathsf{Q}$ weak representability implies strong representability... have I misunderstood the article?

Comment: @Nagase I've edited my answer to address this. Briefly, there's a terminology mix-up, and ultimately no contradiction.

Comment: The edit was *very* helpful. Thanks for this.

Comment: @Nagase After more thought, I've added a couple sources and some discussion about the $\mathsf{Q}$-provably recursive functions.