# Can all $\mathsf{Q}$-provably recursive functions be "frequently termlike"?

Tags: logic, model-theory, computability, proof-theory, nonstandard-models

*Now [asked at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371030/does-mathsfq-have-any-interesting-provably-recursive-functions).*

---

Motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3800181), I'd like to ask whether in a precise sense there are no "interesting" functions which are provably recursive in Robinson's arithmetic [$\mathsf{Q}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic).

For an appropriate theory $T$, say that an **$n$-ary $T$-provably recursive function** is a $\Sigma_1$ formula $\varphi$ with $n+1$ free variables which $T$ proves defines a total function.$^1$ The terms in the language of $T$ itself, as well as their "$\Delta_1$ piecewise combinations," all constitute simple examples of $T$-provably recursive functions. However, in general these account for only a miniscule fragment of the $T$-provably recursive functions. For example, *(the usual sequence-based definition of)* exponentiation is $\mathsf{PA}$-provably recursive, but is also $\mathsf{PA}$-provably eventually different from every $\{+,\times\}$-term.

I'm interested in whether $\mathsf{Q}$ has any such "surprising" provably recursive functions:

> Is there any $\mathsf{Q}$-provably recursive function $\varphi(x_1,...,x_n,y)$ such that for every $\{+,\times\}$-term $t(x_1,...,x_n,z_1,...,z_k)$ we have $$\mathsf{Q}\vdash\forall z_1,...,z_k \exists x\forall x_1, ..., x_n[\bigwedge_{1\le i\le n}x_i>x\implies \neg\varphi(x_1,...,x_n,t(x_1,...,x_n, z_1,...,z_k))]?$$

Intuitively, I'm asking whether there is a $\mathsf{Q}$-provably recursive function which is $\mathsf{Q}$-provably eventually different from every term. Note that "eventually different" here is used in the sense of "different on all inputs with each coordinate sufficiently large." In particular, a function like $$\varphi(x_1,x_2,y)\equiv (y=0\wedge x_1=x_2)\vee(y=1\wedge x_1\not=x_2)$$ is **not** an example; it is "not eventually the same as" any term, but that's a much weaker condition.

A negative answer would say to me that the class of $\mathsf{Q}$-provably recursive functions is "almost trivial" (which is not to say uninteresting, to be fair).

---

$^1$Usually we draw a distinction between the function itself and the formula $\varphi$, but since we always wind up talking about $\varphi$ specifically there's nothing lost by focusing on it right from the beginning.

Comment: I think $(y=1\land x_1=x_2)\lor(y=0\land\neg x_1=x_2)$ is a counterexample. (I always use Shoenfield's $N$ where other people use Robinson's $Q$. So anything I say about $Q$ should be taken with a grin of salt. With $N$, I could also use the characteristic function of $<$ as a counterexample, and I have reason to think it might work in $Q$ too.) (I decided not to correct the typo "grin of salt" because I rather like it.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Unless I'm having a silly moment, that's not a counterexample - it's "consistently (indeed provably) infinitely often" equal to the term $0$ (or $1$ for that matter). That is, there is no $x$ such that for all $x_1>x,x_2>x$ we have $\neg \varphi(x_1,x_2,0)$. A counterexample would be a function which $\mathsf{Q}$-provably avoids each term on all inputs with all coordinates sufficiently large. (That said, I strongly approve of grins of salt.)

Comment: You're right; I misread the formula in your answer.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I've edited to clarify this; let me know if it could be further improved.