# Meaning of Provable recursiveness

Tags: number-theory, first-order-logic, computability, peano-axioms, formal-systems

Is there any difference between provably total function  and provable recursiveness of a function in first order PA ?

From provably total I mean that the totality of the function itself is provable in the theory...  I know this is true of every total recursive function in PA , it can prove the totality of a given total recursive function..

But I get confuse with the term provable recursiveness  when reading about it in Stanford Plato website...

Answer (score 1):

There is some variance of usage, but **usually** "provably total" and "provably recursive" are indeed synonymous. That said, [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3800181/provably-total-functions-in-mathsfq/3801031#3801031) for a case where they aren't! Always check the precise definition in your source. Basically, the key point is that we usually restrict attention to "low-complexity" defining formulas, which prevent a silly trick from making all total recursive functions provably total via "pathological" definitions.

That said, there's a fundamental error in your question:

> "I know this is true of every total recursive function in PA"

This is false, at least when we restrict attention to low-complexity definitions (which is usually done per the above): any total recursive function $f$ is (strongly) representable in PA, but that does **not** mean that PA can prove that $f$ is total. All PA can do is prove, for each specific $n$, that $f(n)$ is defined; PA cannot in general prove "For all $n$, $f(n)$ is defined." (This is exactly analogous to how PA can prove, for each specific $n$, that there is no contradiction in PA involving at most $n$ symbols, but PA cannot prove "For all $n$ there is no contradiction in PA involving at most $n$ symbols.")

Comment: Can you suggest any easy to follow proof/material stating there are total recursive functions not provably total in PA..., I didn't knew about it before...  I need to check it ... I actually must check it...

Comment: Also I still can't understand how will you represent the predicate of contradiction proofs in PA,  can you show me that predicate which is true if there isn't a contradiction proof less than x in PA ?